# How to send json in response at Get Endpoint Odoo v11

Tags: python, json, controller, odoo, odoo-11

Currently trying to call  a odoo controller which return json data as per my exception.

```
@http.route('/web/update_order_webhook', type='http', csrf=False, auth="public")
def update_order_webhook(self, **kwargs):
    return Response(json.dumps({"yes":"i am json"}),content_type='application/json;charset=utf-8',status=200)
```

When I tried to call this end point

```
import requests

url = "http://159.89.197.219:8069/web/update_order_webhook"

headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I get Request Body

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Invalid JSON data: ''</p>
```

And Request Header at my calling end point

```
content-length →137
content-type →text/html
date →Thu, 11 Jan 2018 20:32:53 GMT
server →Werkzeug/0.13 Python/3.5.2
```

that clearly mean that I am not getting json response data from my odoo endpoint. 
As per last answer I had update my code

```
@http.route('/web/update_order_webhook', type='json', auth="public", website=True)
    def update_order_webhook(self, **kwargs):
         return json.dumps({"yes":"i am json"})
```

But now I got new error while I called my endpoint

```
Bad Request
<function Binary.update_order_webhook at 0x7efd82ac8510>, /web/update_order_webhook: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'json' but called with a request of type 'http'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an update to your question, I invite you to check the link bellow, it treat the same issue as yours :
https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/web-webclient-version-info-function-declared-as-capable-of-handling-request-of-type-json-but-called-with-a-request-of-type-http-100834

So the solution was to set the python method as you already have done with the type 'json', also use a 'POST method when requesting the server, in the client side you have to make a GET request and get the result from the json field.

The python method will be :

```
@http.route('/web/update_order_webhook',methods=['POST'], type='json', csrf=False, auth="public")
    def update_order_webhook(self, **kwargs):
        return Response(json.dumps({"yes":"i am json"}),content_type='application/json;charset=utf-8',status=200)
```

The client side will be :

```
import requests
url = "http://159.89.197.219:8069/web/update_order_webhook"
payload = {'key1':'val1','key2':'val2'}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
print(response.text)
print(response.json())
```

Check this url to see more details about the new way to make requests in pyhton :
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

> End of update

To replace the header type of your request :text/html if you want to return an HTMl response, otherwise the response type of the method must be 'json'

```
@http.route('/web/update_order_webhook', type='json', csrf=False, auth="public")
def update_order_webhook(self, **kwargs):
    return Response(json.dumps({"yes":"i am json"}),content_type='application/json;charset=utf-8',status=200)
```

Also take a look at this example from the odoo github repo :
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/calendar/controllers/main.py

the accept method of the calendar main controller :

```
@http.route('/calendar/meeting/accept', type='http', auth="calendar")
    def accept(self, db, token, action, id, **kwargs):
        registry = registry_get(db)
        with registry.cursor() as cr:
            env = Environment(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {})
            attendee = env['calendar.attendee'].search([('access_token', '=', token), ('state', '!=', 'accepted')])
            if attendee:
                attendee.do_accept()
        return self.view(db, token, action, id, view='form')
```

If you look at the return of this method you will notice that it's a view (a form view ) so the response type is http

In the same file you will find the method notify_ack that returns a json response so the type is set to 'json'

```
@http.route('/calendar/notify_ack', type='json', auth="user")
    def notify_ack(self, type=''):
        return request.env['res.partner']._set_calendar_last_notif_ack()
```

Comment: No I want content type Json Only in return

Comment: I updated the my answer, check it and tell me if it works.

Comment: I had solved this issue by adding db filter at odoo conf file . Because my server had multiple database .So requester couldn't understand which db it had to request. Thanks for your effort and time

Comment: I am accepting your answer because i have a new issue <record id="confirm_sale_order" model="ir.actions.server">
     <field name="name">Confirm Sale Orders</field>
  <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order" />
  <field name="code">
        
            action = {
                "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
                "view_mode": "tree",
                "res_model": object.sale.order,
                "res_id": object.action_confirm_sale_order,
            }
    </field>

Comment: I want to add item in menu action in odoo 11 using ir.action.server if you have any idea how i can do this then Please do update me. I am stuck at that point. Its not showing my menu item.here is official link you can undertsand it better then Please read it https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/actions.html#code

Comment: I want to add item to action menu in sale.order tree view . Thanks for your time

Comment: Why not accepting my answer without a chantage ?;
If I have well understood your issue , corresponding to your code you want simply to call an "act_window" so you have to reference directly the action from the menu that you will create, if you want to call a server action from the menu reference it in the action field action="confirm_sale_order" .

Comment: Thanks I had solved this too . You are great person. Thanks for your support that's why i love stack.

Answer (score 1):

For your route. Use the type="json" flag.

```
@http.route('/web/update_order_webhook', type='json', auth="public", website=True)
def update_order_webhook(self, **kwargs):
    return json.dumps({"yes":"i am json"})
```

Comment: I do not think that should matter.

Comment: okay @Phillip I will implement this and if it got worked i will accept your answer Thanks for your time Sir

Comment: Bad Request
<function Binary.update_order_webhook at 0x7efd82ac8510>, /web/update_order_webhook: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'json' but called with a request of type 'http'

Comment: @http.route('/web/update_order_webhook', type='json', auth="public", website=True) as per your instructions . I had updated my code . Now   i got  this error

Comment: I think the issue is with your request.

Comment: You may need to pass json data with the request. Even if it is '{}'

Answer (score 0):

**Yes. ODOO HTTP GET METHOD 100% WORKS, JUST FOLLOW MY GUIDANCE.**

Controller should be  type='json', not type='http'

*"Hussain Ali" Absolute right on his Qustation, as solution with GET method I wrote below for ODOO*

**Note:** I had given you solution with my sample code, you had to correct parameters as I had explain below.

```
import requests

url = "https://dev-expert.snippetbucket.com/api/get_user_information/"


headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'user-token': "02BXD2AGqVH-TEJASTANK-gg92DwntD8f1p0tb",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }
payload = "{\"params\": {}}"
response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

This solution absolute 100% works, Just data=payload need to add, that's works with odoo, latest versionn 13.0 as well. As of version 14 not release so can't say.

Solution works with odoo community and enterprise version as well.

**Special Note:**
Story behind seen, odoo type='json' in controller does not mean http json request. type='json' its json-rpc.

Regards,
Tejas - SnippetBucket.com